# Vue file not showing

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to show .Vue file but it is not happening.

In inspect, it shows the vue file but does not give the output

`<Root>
  <ImageComponent>
  <Om>`

ScreenShot of inspect
[image: ScreenShot]

This is my app.js file

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

 Vue.component('image-component', require('./components/ImageuploadComponent.vue'));
 Vue.component('Om', require('./components/Om.vue'));

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */


 const app =

    new Vue({
   el: '#chat',
 });
```

./components/ImageuploadComponent.vue
(./components/Om.vue same as this one only header and body content is different)

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

blade.php file has

```
<div id="chat">
    <image-component></image-component>
    <Om></Om>
</div>

<script src="{{ url('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Thank You

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console? What about inspecting the elements in the Elements tab of the browser's developer tools, what elements do you see there?

Comment: Can you see the console.log('Component mounted.') in the browser console  ?

Comment: Have you tried naming it in lowercase and renaming it to `OmComponent.vue`

Answer (score 1):

Thank You Every One i Got the solution For my error

```
 Vue.component('Om', require('./components/Om.vue').default);
```

The `.default();` was missing.